# Python SQLite3 Pass Blob GUID from a Result to a Query

Tags: python, sqlite, blob, guid

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so apologies if I get anything wrong.

I'm fairly new to Python, and I have SQLite3 database which is created by an application I use, therefore I cannot alter the format of the db.

I have two tables, the main one which creates entries and assigns a unique ID in a column of data type GUID. This same GUID is then used in a second table to cross reference the item and store multiple additional entries.

What I need to do, is update one row of the main table, and then update any matching rows in the second table that have matching GUID's.

The problem is how can I pass the Blob value retrieved from the primary result into next query?

Thanks in advance.

Example: In theory I want to achieve the following..

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')

aCsr = conn.execute("SELECT * from MainTable")
for aRow in aCsr:
    bQry = "SELECT * from SecondTable WHERE GUID=" + row[16]
    bCsr = conn.execute(bQry)
    for bRow in bCsr:
        print bRow[0]

conn.close()
```

Comment: far too broad. Post some code

Comment: Have updated my original post

Comment: I don't see any SQL `UPDATE` in your code example. What you are doing is basically a `JOIN`. What do you want to update?

Comment: No but my problem is forming a valid query. Then I can focus on my update. In other words I haven't got that far.

Comment: What is the actual type of the vales in the GUID column?

Comment: Using an SQLite viewer, the fields are formatted like '015ADF09-535E-D84F-95B3-E5C7273D4CF5' If I try to convert these in anything meaningful, such as a string or bytes I get something like '�����>�G��#E>S�' The data type within the SQLite database is listed as 'guid' which I assume is a custom data type?